# how add object cimg in Qwidget

Tags: qt, qwidget, qimage, cimg

I am creating an application in qt and use cimg to handle the graphics. My question is how I put an item CImg  within a QWidget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a QImage, if the CImg internal format is one of the options QImage supports you can create a QImage wrapper that uses the CImg data without needing a copy - otherwise you might have to copy the CImg bytes into the QImage.data